# Why can't I POST data from a Modal to PHP?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the following code, a modal within a form with method="POST" but in the php-part the submitted value is not read. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

```
                <?php
                if ($error) {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error.'</div>';
                }

                if ($message) {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$message.'</div>';
                }
                ?>

<div class="container"> 
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch modal
    </button>

    <form method="post">                

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">You will receive an Access Code at your new email-address</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="text">Fill in your Access Code right here</label>
                    <input type="text" name="AccessCode" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-lg marginTop" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

The php part looks like this:

```
<?php 

if ($_POST['submit']=='Confirm') {
    print_r($_POST);
    $error="No errors";
    $message="Approved!";
} else {
    $error="Error!";
    $message="Nothing received";
}

?>
```

Comment: your form has no action...

Comment: having no action is not a problem but the action tag should be placed like `action=""` and it will send the info to the same page.

Comment: @AresDraguna that IS an action... "" is just a self location reference.

Comment: I know, I just explained it in a way that the OP would understand providing that he did not specify it to begin with ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form needs an action ..

```
<form method="post">
```

Has no idea where it is supposed to post the information to.

```
<form method="post" action="phpPageToSendTo.php">
```

will work..

To test, at the top of your page in the php section add in

```
$testValue = "";
if(isset($_POST["AccessCode"]))
{
   $testValue = $_POST["AccessCode"] ;
   echo "<h1> BIG LETTERS WITH THE ACCESS CODE :" . $testValue . "</h1>";
}
?>
```

Now in your form HTML item use the `action=""` Run the page and test the form.

### Resolution :

And it seems you cannot have another event attached to your submit.. `data-dismiss="modal"`.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work either. I just want to send it to the php-code elsewhere on the same page: <?php (some code) ?>

Comment: @Arnold to send the form data to the same page use `action=""` in your form html tag. 
I will update the answer with an example

Comment: No, that doesn't do it. Besides, in a normal form (that is, not a modal) the posting works fine, even without the action clause!

Comment: @Arnold maybe im missing something then.. remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from the sumbit button

Comment: Yes! That's what caused the problem. Thank you very much for solving it!

Comment: Sidenote: As noted in comments, form defaults to self when action is omitted. Your answer should reflect that, including the comment you left about removing `data-dismiss="modal"` from the submit button.

Comment: @Fred-ii- great stuff, learn something new everyday. Didnt know that myself -> updated answer

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that myself till today (about `data-dismiss="modal"`). Just cuz I have 23k rep, doesn't mean I know more than the other guy hahaha! We all learn something. *Cheers* +1