# bootstrap modal contact form issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with a bootstrap modal contact form, everything seems to work as planned in all browsers except on iPad/safari, can anyone please shed any light on where I'm going wrong?

1. When viewing on iPad the modal is offset to the right and moved down
   the page, not sitting in the middle where it should be.
2. When user selects a field in the form the cursor is not in the field
   itself, it is located outside of the modal window flashing in the
   greyed out background.
3. When user types in a field the text is not shown within the field
   until the next field is selected, then the text appears.

As I said everything is working fine in I.E. and Chrome these issues only occur with safari. Something is breaking my layout when viewed with Apple device.

Page can be viewed at http://odds-uk.co.uk/abbeystone/contact.php

There's quite a lot going on in the page with validation, modals, maps and tabs etc. so I wonder if I have a conflict somewhere I'm fairly new to web programming (year 2 degree student) so please forgive any stupid errors, I do hope someone can help as I'm stumped for ideas at present. Thankyou in advance.
Roy

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>     
        <!-- Include Google map API link -->
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDe94CcWCoY8mk1niRhZLBNc5bxst5CZNg"></script>      

        <!--<meta name="description" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">-->
        <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
        <title>Contact Property Management</title>

        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--<link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
        <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>  



        <script>
            var Maldon = new google.maps.LatLng(51.731897, 0.677035);

            function initializeMaldon()
                {
                var mapProp1 = {
                  center:Maldon,
                  zoom:15,
                  scrollwheel: false,
                  draggable: false,
                  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  };

                var map1=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap1"),mapProp1);

                var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:Maldon,
                  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                  });

                marker1.setMap(map1);

                var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content:"<img class='logopad' src='images/logo.png' width='140px' alt='Abbeystone Property Management Logo'>",
                  maxWidth: 140
                  });

                infowindow1.open(map1,marker1);
                }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMaldon);


            /*The following map wouldnt show properly within hidden Tab so set a timer on it
            www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
            www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4064275/how-to-deal-with-google-map-inside-of-a-hidden-div-updated-picture*/

            var refreshIntervalId;

            function showMap() {
                document.getElementById('googleMap2').style.display = '';
                refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () { updateMapTimer() }, 10);
            }

            function updateMapTimer() {
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                var Norwich = new google.maps.LatLng(52.627970, 1.298478);  

                var mapProp2 = {
                  center:Norwich,
                  zoom:15,
                  scrollwheel: false,
                  draggable: false,
                  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  };

                var map2=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap2"),mapProp2);

                var marker2=new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:Norwich,
                  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                  });

                marker2.setMap(map2);

                var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content:"<img class='logopad' src='images/logo.png' width='140px' alt='Abbeystone Property Management Logo'>",
                  maxWidth: 140
                  });  

                infowindow2.open(map2,marker2);
            }

        </script>   

    </head>
<body>
<div class="container fill">

    <?php include 'header.php';?>

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

        <div class='LogoOverlay'>
            <div class="">                                     
                <div class="LogoImage"><img src="images/homepage/OmbudsmanLogo.png" alt="Ombudsman Service Logo"></div>
                <div class="LogoImage"><img src="images/homepage/ARMA-logo.jpg" alt="ARMA Logo"></div>                
                <div class="LogoImage"><img src="images/homepage/FedOfMastBuildLogo.gif" alt="Fed. of Master Builders Logo"></div>
            </div>                   
        </div>   

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
              <div class="fill" style='background-image: url("images/homepage/home2.jpg");'>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row nomargin">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 contFrame">
                            <div class="row " id="ContactDiv">                                 

                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs " id="myTab">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Head Office</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#tab2" onclick="showMap()" data-toggle="tab">Norwich Branch</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <div class="tab-content my-tab">

                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <h3 class="moveDown10">Contact </h3>
                                                <hr />
                                                <p>

                                                </p>
                                                <hr />
                                                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>  <b>01621 842711</b></h4>    
                                                <hr />
                                                    <div class="container">
                                                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">  </span> Send us a message</a> 
                                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Messaging</h4>
                                                                </div> <!--end modal-header--> 
                                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                                    <hr>


                                                                    <form id="messageMaldon" class="form-horizontal"method="POST" action="send_form_email.php">
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">     
                                                                                <input class="form-control required" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" value="" type="text" title="Please enter your Name">        
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                                <input class="form-control required email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" type="text" title="Please enter a valid Email address">           
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>  
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                                <input class="form-control required number" name="inputPhone" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone"  value="" type="text" title="Please enter your Phone Number using numbers only">
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>      
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                                                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                                <textarea class="form-control required" name="inputMessage" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea>
                                                                                <!--<button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" value="submit">Send!</button>-->
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-6">                    
                                                                                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" >Send</button>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>        
                                                                    </form> 

                                                                </div> <!--end modal-body--> 
                                                            </div> <!--end modal-content--> 
                                                        </div> <!--end modal-dialog--> 
                                                    </div><!-- end myModal-->   
                                                </div>  

                                            </div><!-- end col-sm-4-->                                                                             

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 map "> 
                                                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>    Our Location</h4> 
                                                <div id="googleMap1"></div>              
                                            </div>                                 
                                        </div><!-- end tab-pane -->

                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <h3 class="moveDown10">Contact </h3>
                                                <hr>
                                                <p>

                                                </p>
                                                <hr />
                                                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>  <b></b></h4>    
                                                <hr>
                                                <div class="container">                 
                                                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-custom " data-toggle="modal">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">  </span> Send us a message</a> 
                                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Messaging</h4>
                                                                </div> <!--end modal-header--> 
                                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                                    <hr>

                                                          <!--      <form class="form-horizontal">
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                            <input class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                            <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" type="email">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                            <input class="form-control" id="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone" type="phone">
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>                                                            
                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputMessage">Message</label>
                                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea>
                                                                            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Send!</button>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                </form>-->
                                                                </div> <!--end modal-body--> 
                                                            </div> <!--end modal-content--> 
                                                        </div> <!--end modal-dialog--> 
                                                    </div><!-- end myModal-->   
                                                </div>  

                                            </div><!-- end col-sm-4-->                         

                                            <div class="col-sm-8 map "> 
                                                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>    Our Location</h4> 
                                                <div id="googleMap2"></div>              
                                            </div>                                    
                                        </div><!-- end tab-pane --> 

                                    </div><!-- end tab-content -->    

                            </div><!--end ContactDiv-->                             
                        </div>
                    <!--end col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1--> 
                    </div><!--end row-->                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>   

    <!-- All Javascript at the bottom of the page for faster page loading -->

    <!-- First try for the online version of jQuery-->
    <script src="includes/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- If no online access, fallback to our hardcoded version of jQuery -->
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>



    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>   

    <!-- jQuery validation -->  
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>  

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#messageMaldon').validate();
        }); // end ready
    </script> 


</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['inputEmail'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "blah@blahblahblah.net";
    $email_subject = "Customer Enquiry";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['inputName']) ||
        !isset($_POST['inputPhone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['inputEmail']) ||        
        !isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $inputName = $_POST['inputName']; // required
    $inputPhone = $_POST['inputPhone']; // required
    $inputEmail = $_POST['inputEmail']; // required    
    $inputMessage = $_POST['inputMessage']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z\s.'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$inputName)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $num_exp = "/^[0-9\s.'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($num_exp,$inputPhone)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$inputEmail)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }  
  if(strlen($inputMessage) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Message sent via Contact page on Abbeystone Website.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($inputName)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($inputPhone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($inputEmail)."\n";   
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($inputMessage)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$inputEmail."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$inputEmail."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
//sleep(3);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=http://www.abbeystone.net/contact.php\">";
echo "<script>alert('Thankyou your message was sent successfully.'); </script> ";
}
?>
```

Comment: try to edit your question and add some code to see where you fail. I recommend you to take a look to the tour to improve your questions and have good answers http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: okay thankyou I will Shudy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529124/why-cant-i-post-data-from-a-modal-to-php/26529169#comment41686675_26529169 take a look here

Comment: you are welcome @royG . If for some reason (low  reputation) you cannot add images, links or something you need, you can add in a comment and someone will edit you post with it. For images upload it to some page and paste the link.

Comment: thankyou @Shudy Ive added code now and taken the tour.

Comment: thankyou @Pogrindis but I cant see the relevance to that link could you be more specific please?

Comment: perfect @royG hope, some one can help you ;) and remember the tips to good question: 1-explain your case, 2-post code and error logs, 3 - ask a concise question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me to be the positioning within the html markup of the #myModal element that is causing safari to render the modal as if it was a child element (as indeed that is how you have positioned it).

From the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> **Modal markup placement**
>
> Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Also the way in which the modal renders in chrome doesn't seem to be ideal either as it renders under the header and footer elements - rather that being on-top of all page elements (but as it is centred this is less noticeable).

To fix the issue reposition the modal div and its contents from after the trigger button to before the `</body>` close tag:

**Broken Markup (current)**

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">  </span> Send us a message
</a>
//reposition as below to fix
<div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">
  //form and stuff...
</div>
```

**Fixed Markup**

```
  <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">
    //form and stuff...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @David Anderton , I haven't tried it yet as Im up against the clock on another project, but I think youre right so I'll have a go and get back to you asap, really appreciate your time and detailed response :)

Comment: You are welcome - you can ping me directly if it doesn't sort out your issue (see profile).

Comment: It worked a treat :) Thank you @David Anderton I'm hugely grateful I'm loving Bootstrap but still a novice, so help with these quirks is fantastic.Cheers

Comment: Let me point you towards https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YJUFaZMS8Q this guy is awesome and was really helpful while I was learning the nuances of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Modal markup placement

Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.